# Remove woocommerce duplicate taxonomy page links?

Tags: woocommerce, duplicates, taxonomy

I am having an issue with duplicate content, which seems to be an out of the box issue with woocommerce. For example, our SEO company is complaining because of duplicate content because you can go to:

```
http://localhost/wp7/product-category/clothing/hoodies/
```

but you can also go to

```
http://localhost/wp7/product-category/hoodies/
```

So `clothing` is the parent taxonomy of `hoodies`. Is there a filter/code to make it so that you won't be able to navigate to just the child taxonomy link, but only allow `http://www.example.com/product-category/parent/child`?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards, and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work through this, with this solution. Which seems to work beautifully. Not sure of the repercussions in the woocommerce eco system, but it definitely works on the frontend.

```
/**
 * Disallow duplicate Woocommerce taxonomy links
 * |- Redirects http://www.example.com/product_cat/child to http://www.example.com/product_cat/parent/child
 */
add_action('template_redirect', function ($query) {
    global $wp;
    $productCatTaxonomy = 'product_cat';

    if (is_tax($productCatTaxonomy)) {
        $current_url = add_query_arg($wp->query_string, '', home_url($wp->request));
        $current_args = parse_url($current_url);
        $currentTerm = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var('term'), $productCatTaxonomy);

        if (isset($current_args['query']) && !stristr($current_args['query'], '%2f')) {
            $currentParentTerm = (isset($currentTerm->parent) && $currentTerm->term_id) ? get_term_by('id', $currentTerm->parent, $productCatTaxonomy) : 0;

            if ($currentParentTerm) {
                $childTermLink = (isset($currentTerm->term_id) && $currentTerm->term_id) ? get_term_link($currentTerm->term_id, $productCatTaxonomy) : 0;

                if ($childTermLink) {
                    wp_redirect($childTermLink);
                    die();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $query;
});
```